# Can I put two list data in SharedPreferences (flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

### **i need to save 2 list(list book,list tool) in page favorite but the problem is the list book is save in page favorite and the list tool is not save**

---

> **that the list book file**

```
List<Book> Books_Data = [
  Book(
    id: 'b1',
    categories: [
      'c1',

    ],
    title: 'الوصايا العشر في الامن السيبراني',
writer:'محمد شاكر المبيض',
    price:'5500 ل.س',
    imageUrl:
        'assets/image/Book/1.jpg',
    page: 64,   
  ),
      
 ]
```

---

> **and that the list tool file**

```
List<Tools> tools_Data = [
  Tools(
    id: 't1',
    categories: [
      'c1',

    ],
    title: 'قلم رصاص ميكانيكي',
    price:'750 ل.س',
    imageUrl:
        'assets/image/Tools/1.jpg',
  ),
   
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to convert your class object to JSON by obj.toJson(); and save the json String into Storage and refactor the json String to your obj class by obj.fromJson();

Answer (score 0):

I think that a simple solution is to convert your list into a json string and then save it to shared preferences.

Example:

```
//to convert to json string
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String booksList = jsonDecode(*yourListName*);

prefs.setString("yourTag", bookList);
```

This is how you can save your list. When you need it you have just to:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String json = prefs.getString("yourTag");
var list = jsonEncode(json);
```

This should return you the list you inserted in shared preferences before.

For any question just comment below.